# How to check if webhook posted data is in some table and if not select some data from another table

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, select

I am trying to update ms sql server table's specific field data using webhook posted xml data
the below is php $tsql script

$tsql = "UPDATE Item SET Quantity = (Quantity - '$qty')
         WHERE ItemLookupCode = '$sku'";

'$sku' is from xml data field which is webhook posted but the problem is for example i got 4 '$sku' from xml and 2 of '$sku' is matching with ItemLookupCode in 'Item' Table so i can update but the other 2'$sku' i have to find from another table using different field in another table - Item2(another table's name for example) so after i got 2 '$sku''s specific field in Item2 table i come bact to 'Item' table and i can update Quantity in Item table using different field using the data i got from Item2 table 
i am sorry if i made u confused...
so basically what i am trying to do is if "$sku' from xml matches with ItemLookupCode in Item table then i update the quantity but if "$sku" from xml doen't matches or don't have in another word in Item table's ItemLookupCode then i how do i try to find some data from another table using those '$sku'

(ex) if some item's sku is not in ItemLookupCode column in Item table then use that "$sku" to select some column's specific values in Item2 table to update Item table's Quantity

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: This is a different concern, but you should prepare any variable used in an SQL statement to prevent SQL injection attacks, e.g. by use of something like http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php or http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php etc if you are not doing so already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Item  SET Quantity = (Quantity - '$qty') 
From OtherTable o
WHERE Item.Name=o.Name and o.ItemLookupCode = '$sku'
```